# How to realize/encode a "like" (Facebook) in a database?

Tags: database, database-design

I am coming close to the point where I am going to implement something similar to the Facebook-like or the Google +1. The thing is that I can think of a few ways how to do that but I am not sure what a good one is.

Of course I don't want to lose the information of *who* actually "liked" something so just a simple "counter" won't do it.

The most practical way I could think of was e.g. to use a table `ITEM_LIKE` that looks something like `(ITEM_ID, USER_ID)` and would allow me to get all user ids by an item id (and of course every item "liked" by a user as well). But **I don't know if that scales** and/or if that is enough. Just imagine having hundred thousands of users - would that still be a good way to do it? Because this table would encode every single like made by every single user which means this would become quite large.

Is it that simple or is there a much more sophisticated way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It's that easy. You should also consider adding a date column to this table, and make the combination of user_id and item_id the primary key of the table.
Most modern databases should be able to handle a table like this with tens of millions of rows easily.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I'm glad to hear that not everything has to be complicated. What I don't understand is now the date column. That is just to determine *when* the user clicked like, right?